# Show tikzpicture step by step starting from the beginning of a beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pause

I have written the following code to construct a slide in beamer.
I would like the graph in the `tikzpicture` in the right column to be visible since the beginning of the slide, except for the rounded blue rectangles I define inside the `tikzpicture`, which should appear at the second step.
Moreover, what I achieved so far "moves" the graph when those rectangles are displayed (going from step 1 to step 2): that should not happen!

Could you help me?

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Frankfurt}
    \useinnertheme{default}
    \useoutertheme{default}
    \usecolortheme{default}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=black,bg=Blue!10}
    \setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=OliveGreen!20}
    \setbeamercolor{postit2}{fg=yellow,bg=OliveGreen}
}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em, text margin right=2em}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TITLE}
    \begin{columns}[c]
        \begin{column}{.75\textwidth}
        The black graph should already be visible...\\
        \smallskip
        \pause
        Here the blue rectangles should appear and remain visible until the end...\\
        \smallskip
        \pause
        Line 3...\\
        \smallskip
        \pause
        Line 4...\\
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
           \visible<1->{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,vertex/.style={
    circle,fill=black,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt}]
                %% vertices
                \node[vertex] (V1) at (0,0) {};
                \node[vertex] (V2) at (.5,1) {};
                \node[vertex] (V3) at (1.5,1.5) {};
                \node[vertex] (V4) at (1,.5) {};
                \node[vertex] (V5) at (1,-1) {};
                \node[vertex] (V6) at (.75,-2) {};
                \node[vertex] (V7) at (1.25,-2) {};
                \node[vertex] (V8) at (-.75,-.75) {};
                %% vertex labels
                \node at (-.25,.25) {$a_1$};
                %% edges
                \draw[dashed] (.25,1.75) -- (V2) -- (.75,1.75);
                \draw[dashed] (1.75,.75) -- (V4) -- (1.75,.25);
                \draw[dashed] (V6) -- (.75,-2.5);
                \draw[dashed] (V7) -- (1.25,-2.5);
                \foreach \from/\to in {V1/V2,V2/V3,V3/V4,V4/V1,V1/V5,V5/V6,V5/V7,V1/V8}
                   \draw[thick] (\from) -- (\to);
               %% connected components
               \draw<2->[blue,thick,rounded corners] (.15,.15) rectangle (1.9,1.9) {};
               \draw<2->[blue,thick,rounded corners] (-1.25,-1.25) rectangle (-.25,-.25);
               \draw<2->[blue,thick,rounded corners] (.5,-3) rectangle (1.5,-.5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, give a fully compileable code.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Once the rectangles are displayed, should they remain displayed afterwards or not?

Comment: Yes, they should remain until the end of the slide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder if this is the expected behaviour in [beamer](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) because I think that to get what you want it should be enough to surround the relevant code with `\uncover<1->{...}` etc but this does not work for me. The problem seems to be the previous `\pause` commands, but I am sure that I have done this before. Perhaps the `columns` environment is getting in the way?

Whether this is the intended behaviour or not, you can get around this issue by "resetting" the pause counter by inserting `\pause[0]` before the `tikzpicture` environment. Once you do this `\uncover...` works as expected to produce:

[image]

As shown, if you have material after the `tikzpicture` environment that you want to incrementally display then you need to add `\pause[5]` to resynchronize the pause counter.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Frankfurt}
    \useinnertheme{default}
    \useoutertheme{default}
    \usecolortheme{default}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=black,bg=Blue!10}
    \setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=OliveGreen!20}
    \setbeamercolor{postit2}{fg=yellow,bg=OliveGreen}
}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em, text margin right=2em}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TITLE}
    \begin{columns}[c]
        \begin{column}{.75\textwidth}
        The black graph should already be visible...\\
        \smallskip
        \pause
        Here the blue rectangles should appear and remain visible until the end...\\
        \smallskip
        \pause
        Line 3...\\
        \smallskip
        \pause
        Line 4...\\
        \end{column}
        \pause[0]
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,vertex/.style={
    circle,fill=black,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt}]
                %% vertices
                \uncover<1->{
                  \node[vertex] (V1) at (0,0) {};
                  \node[vertex] (V2) at (.5,1) {};
                  \node[vertex] (V3) at (1.5,1.5) {};
                  \node[vertex] (V4) at (1,.5) {};
                  \node[vertex] (V5) at (1,-1) {};
                  \node[vertex] (V6) at (.75,-2) {};
                  \node[vertex] (V7) at (1.25,-2) {};
                  \node[vertex] (V8) at (-.75,-.75) {};
                  %% vertex labels
                  \node at (-.25,.25) {$a_1$};
                  %% edges
                  \draw[dashed] (.25,1.75) -- (V2) -- (.75,1.75);
                  \draw[dashed] (1.75,.75) -- (V4) -- (1.75,.25);
                  \draw[dashed] (V6) -- (.75,-2.5);
                  \draw[dashed] (V7) -- (1.25,-2.5);
                  \foreach \from/\to in {V1/V2,V2/V3,V3/V4,V4/V1,V1/V5,V5/V6,V5/V7,V1/V8}
                     \draw[thick] (\from) -- (\to);
                }
               %% connected components
               \uncover<2->{
                 \draw[blue,thick,rounded corners] (.15,.15) rectangle (1.9,1.9) {};
                 \draw[blue,thick,rounded corners] (-1.25,-1.25) rectangle (-.25,-.25);
                 \draw[blue,thick,rounded corners] (.5,-3) rectangle (1.5,-.5);
               }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \pause[5]
    Some stuff at the end
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to avoid the shift of the image when the blue rectangles appear?

Comment: @Sirion Sorry, didn't notice that. Use `\uncover` instead of `\only`. I'll edit.